# Convert DocumentSnapshot Data to List

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to read each Object list from the document "list_of_clients" and export it to a custom List that i created

In Realtime Database there is a function called
[GenericTypeIndicator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/GenericTypeIndicator) 
which helps you getting the values, this is similar to what i want but on **Cloud FireStore** there is no such function

I'm very new to android and i don't know how much more i can explain this
but here are some pics:

This is my DataBase:
[image: mydb]

This is my user_list.java

```
private String user_addr;
private String user_name;
private String user_phone;


public user_list(String user_addr, String user_name, String user_phone) {
    this.user_addr = user_addr;
    this.user_name = user_name;
    this.user_phone = user_phone;
}

public user_list() {

}

public String getUser_phone() {
    return user_phone;
}

public void setUser_phone(String user_phone) {
    this.user_phone = user_phone;
}

public String getUser_name() {
    return user_name;
}

public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
    this.user_name = user_name;
}

public String getUser_addr() {
    return user_addr;
}

public void setUser_addr(String user_addr) {
    this.user_addr = user_addr;
}
```

What i tried:

```
        db.collection("clients").document("list_of_clients")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        //if read successful

                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();

                        List<user_list> messages = document.getData();

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), document.getId() + " => " + document.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                        //eroare
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Did you try toObject()?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#toObject(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)

Comment: I used this: 

     List<user_list> user_listList = new ArrayList<>();

                            user_list temp_item = document.toObject(user_list.class);
                            user_listList.add(temp_item);

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), user_listList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

but still getting error because of the toast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work, please see the following steps. So, in order to deserialize the fields correctly, please consider using a model class that looks like this:

```
public class UserList {
    private String userAddr, userName, userPhone;

    public UserList() {}

    public UserList(String userAddr, String userName, String userPhone) {
        this.userAddr = userAddr;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userPhone = userPhone;
    }

    public String getUserAddr() {return userAddr;}

    public String getUserName() {return userName;}

    public String getUserPhone() {return userPhone;}
}
```

See the naming convention? Firebase will always look after fields that look like `userAddr` and a public getter that look like `getUserAddr()`.

To add a `UserList` object in a correct way to your Cloud Firestore database, please use the following code:

```
UserList userList = new UserList("Bolintin Vale", "Bogdan", "0251206260");
String docId = rootRef.collection("clients").document().getId();
rootRef.collection("clients").document(docId).set(userList);
```

To actually read the data, please use the following code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
rootRef.collection("clients").document("pu8NKFPNUKYgcy0yOitW").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        UserList userList = documentSnapshot.toObject(UserList.class);
        Log.d(TAG, userList.getUserName());
    }
});
```

As you can see, I have used in my code the `pu8NKFPNUKYgcy0yOitW` id that was generated before. The output will be:

```
Bogdan
```

Bafta! ;)

Comment: This means every time i add a new client, there will be a new document with a random id. I thought using a single document and putting objects inside of it is more efficient.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, a new document with a random id for each user. This is what the documents are for. You cannot add too many objects in a document because there is a limit of 1MB/per document, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo You didn't answer how to get all documents as list, you just retreived 1 document

Comment: @LukaSamkharadze The OP asked about a UserList object.