# How to parse Object of Map<String, Object> returned from documentSnapshot.getData() of Google Cloud Firestore into a POJO?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore, pojo

documentSnapshot.getData() method of Cloud Firestore returns a Map< String, Object >. My db structure looks like below:

[image: Database Structure/Schema]

Now I have a POJO as below:

```
public class Plan {

    private ArrayList<String> items;
    private String name;
    private int price;
    private int years;

    public Plan() {
    }

    public Plan(ArrayList<String> items, String name, int price, int years) {
        this.items = items;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.years = years;
    }

    public List<String> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<String> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getYears() {
        return years;
    }

    public void setYears(int years) {
        this.years = years;
    }
}
```

As you see, all I want is a list of Object from the Map< String, Object > returned from documentSnapshot.getData() method. The String, i.e., the key part, has to be ignored. I don't want to use keys to extract from Map as I want the algorithm to dynamically create a list of all plans (POJO) irrespective of the number of key-value pairs in the map.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
documentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                    Map<String, Object> planMap = documentSnapshot.getData();
                    // how to parse the Object inside Map<String, Object> above to POJO Plan.class here
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

I tried many ways but I am unable to parse that Object into my POJO. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `List<Plan> plans = documentSnapshots.toObjects(Plan.class);`

Comment: Cannot resolve method toObjects

Comment: can you add code that you are using?

Comment: @Niraj added above

Comment: okay, adding answer below.

Comment: @Rahul are you trying to do this out side your POJO? I ask b/c your POJO fields, specifically the access modifier are declared as private. I don't see any getter or setters as part of your POJO.

Comment: @VictorS I have added full POJO above. Please provide insights if any.

Comment: @Rahul your POJO allows access to you instance variables via your constructor. I assume you made them private for a good reason. Consider removing the constructor.

Comment: Ok thank you for the improvement suggestion

Comment: Have you solved the issue? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo There is no solution to the problem I have. Hence, I used a different approach to solve this issue. I changed my db schema from a map to an array and created a POJO that has an arraylist attribute and converted the document into that POJO directly. This way it works for any number of values in the array (document).

Comment: I know it is not the solution, but could you post the workaround you came up with as an answer, for community purposes?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is, you should use the same POJO class that you were using to save the data. As it is a complex class and has object of Plan class so if you use that one it will be better. Let your original class name is Familiy_pack.

```
documentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                   Family_pack f = documentSnapshots.toObject(Family_pack .class);


                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Now, use can easily get the values from Plan object.

Comment: Even this won't work. If you observe my db schema, "name" is not directly accessible. It is within the value part of each key-value pair. Also note that there can be any number of key-value pairs in the document and the algorithm should adapt to it.

Comment: Can you please add the code, how you save the data in firestore. If used any POJO do add that too @Rahul.

Comment: This method won't work as I said before that I want the logic to work for any number of key-value pair in the document. This way I'll have to pre-create a class for each key-value pair which is not a good approach.

Answer (score -1):

Update: Refer [Convert DocumentSnapshot Data to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49266445/convert-documentsnapshot-data-to-list) as you want list of object

Official documentations says

```
 <T> T toObject(Class<T> valueType) - 
 Returns the contents of the document converted to a POJO or null if the document doesn't exist.
```

so try

```
Plan plan = documentSnapshots.toObject(Plan.class);
```

Ref - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot

Comment: Please read my question properly. I don't want to convert the document directly into a POJO. I want only the values part of the document as a list of POJO.

Comment: @Rahul I read the title and the comment "// how to parse the Object inside Map<String, Object> above to POJO Plan.class here" and understood that you want Pojo object. Updating my ans to get a list. Probably you may like to update you question title too.

Comment: The updated answer still doesn't solve my problem. Please understand my use case. Please have a look at db schema. I don't wish to have separate documents in a collection. I need to have multiple document-like data in a single document because they will always be fetched together so unnecessary multiple document fetches that increase cost. Did you get it? Please let me know if you need more info

Answer (score -1):

try `QuerySnapshot` instead of `DocumentSnapshot`:

```
documentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if (documentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: LIST EMPTY");
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Convert the whole Query Snapshot to a list
                    // of objects directly! No need to fetch each
                    // document.
                    List<Plan> plans = documentSnapshot.toObjects(Plan.class);   

                    // Add all to your list
                    mArrayList.addAll(types);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: " + mArrayList);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<? super DocumentSnapshot>) in Task cannot be applied to (anonymous OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>)